# How do I get the index of an array where it contains a string?

Tags: javascript

```
var qs = ["color=green", "pet=dog", "fruit=apple]
```

I want to get fruit. Tried:

```
for (var j=0; j<qs.length; j++) {qs[j].indexOf('fruit')}
```

That returned 0.

I expected it to return 2, the last entry int he array? How do I find which array value is the one I want?

Comment: so you want to get the index of the array that contains the word fruit?

Comment: `qs.findIndex(s => s.includes('fruit'))`.

Comment: Just return `qs[j]`.. If `indexOf > -1`

Comment: @FelixKling - hadn't you better mention browser compatibility :p

Comment: @JaromandaX: That's why it's a comment ;)

Comment: @FelixKling - well played, sir :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, you need to do a break on the index or make a new array and push the ones with matching indexes into that array

```
var arr = [];

for (var j=0; j<qs.length; j++) 
{
    if(qs[j].indexOf('fruit')!==-1){
        arr.push(j);
    }
}
//print all the indexes that contain fruit
for(var i in arr)
console.log(arr[i]);
```

If you just want one index just break

```
var matchingIdx=-1;
for (var j=0; j<qs.length; j++) 
{
    if(qs[j].indexOf('fruit')!==-1){
       matchingIdx = j;
       break;
    }
}
```

and if you want to generalize this can put it into a function

```
function gettingMatchingIndexes(qs, target) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var j=0; j<qs.length; j++) 
    {
        if(qs[j].indexOf(target)!==-1){
            arr.push(j);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: OP is not expecting an `array` but an `index`

Comment: @Rayon right, this is an array of all the indexes that match, if he wants just one when you find it rather than putting it in an array

Comment: Thank you very much I probably should have thought about it more before posting

Answer (score 1):

Just return `j` if you just want the index of the first element contains 'fruit' in the array.

```
function findFirstFruitIndex() {
 for (var j = 0; j < qs.length; j++) {
  if (qs[j].indexOf('fruit') > -1) return j;
 }
}
```

`qs[j].indexOf('fruit')` returns the position of 'fruit' in `qs[j]`, instead of the position of `qs[j]` in `qs` (which you want).

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere in the string:

```js
let qs = ["color=green", "pet=dog", "fruit=apple]"];
let res = qs.findIndex(e => e.includes('fruit'));
console.log(res);
```

Exact match on the key:

```js
let qs = ["color=green", "pet=dog", "fruit=apple]"];
let res = qs.findIndex(e => e.match(/^fruit=/));
console.log(res);
```

See [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).